# Função recursiva para montar árvore de arquivos

Tags: php, algoritmo, recursão

Estou com problemas para montar uma árvore de diretórios virtuais com seus respectivos arquivos.

A modelagem á seguinte:

Table: **folders**

- id
- name
- company_id
- parent_folder (auto-relacionamento)

Montei a seguinte function:

```
 private function mountTree($folders = [], $folder_id = 0, $include_files = false)
        {
            $tree = [];
            foreach ($folders as $index => $folder) {
                if ($folder['parent_folder'] == $folder_id) {
                    $children = $this->mountTree($folders, $folder['id'], $include_files);
                    if ($children) {
                        $folder['children'] = $children;
                    }
                    if ($include_files) {
                        $folder['files'] = $this->getFilesByFolder($folder['id']);
                    }
                    $tree[$folder['name']] = $folder;
                }                
                unset($folders[$index]);
            }    
            return $tree;
        }
```

O problema é que o meu retorno está trazendo algumas pastas filhas na "raiz" e isso não deveria ocorrer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O correto seria somente a posição 0 do array, nela a estrutura de pastas esta correta.

Por algum motivo algumas subpastas estão sendo duplicadas e indo para a "raiz" (posição 1 do array de exemplo). Essa posição não deveria existir pois essas pastas já estão em seus devidos lugares no array de índice 0.

Código para teste:

```
$folders = [
            0 => [
                "id" => "cc876497-d6a9-4b8a-bf4d-e39a8a416734",
                "name" => "archives",
                "company_id" => "bec5664f-30a2-4ca7-83ea-e6ff5a4ec244",
                "parent_folder" => null,
            ],
              1 =>  [
                "id" => "94cae4aa-0be1-4428-8e5a-e040059a4adf",
                "name" => "N1",
                "company_id" => "bec5664f-30a2-4ca7-83ea-e6ff5a4ec244",
                "parent_folder" => "cc876497-d6a9-4b8a-bf4d-e39a8a416734",

              ],
              2 => [
                "id" => "8426b4bb-8d9f-4ba1-b81c-53f2d350b217",
                "name" => "N2",
                "company_id" => "950e70c2-6791-44da-a74c-fc6e6b7dddc9",
                "parent_folder" => "94cae4aa-0be1-4428-8e5a-e040059a4adf",

              ],
              3 => [
                "id" => "cebb481a-e19c-449e-ad77-3469f08834fd",
                "name" => "N3",
                "company_id" => "950e70c2-6791-44da-a74c-fc6e6b7dddc9",
                "parent_folder" => "8426b4bb-8d9f-4ba1-b81c-53f2d350b217",
              ]

        ];
```

Eu reparei que alterando o id e consequentemente o parent_folder para inteiro o algoritmo funciona de forma correta, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem eu não posso alterar essa estrutura e necessariamente eu preciso trabalhar com uuid (string).

O retorno correto esperado seria a imagem [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PDUy.png), mas utilizando o id e parent_folder como string (uuid).

Comment: Explique com mais detalhes....

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, caso seja necessário adicionar mais informações é só me falar.

Comment: O que é o `$index` em `unset($folders[$index])`? Onde ele foi declarado / definido ?  Os indices dos `children` arrays são inteiros, esse comportamento é o esperado? Eles não deveriam ser uma string correspondente ao nome do direitório, tendo em vista a instrução `$tree[$folder['name']] = $folder;`?

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir o seu erro, confira: https://ideone.com/KE4nz0. Caso a variável `$folders` tenha uma estrutura diferente, seria legal você fornecer uma cópia do conteúdo dela na sua pergunta e caso você esteja invocando a função passando `true` para `$include_files`, seria também necessário você incluir o conteúdo de `$this->getFilesByFolder()`.

Comment: @VanderSantos a variável `$index` é o index do foreach `$folders`. Eu coloquei um array de dados para simular o caso real que está acontecendo o problema.

Comment: Como seria a saída correta?

Comment: @AugustoVasques coloquei no final como seria a saída correta.

Comment: O problema é comigo, ou mais alguém não entendeu coisa alguma dessa questão?

Comment: @AugustoVasques querendo ou não você me auxiliou bastante. Cheguei em uma solução e já vou postar. Já deixo aqui o meu agradecimento.

Comment: Agora ficou fácil. O erro está na sua comparação de strings. Substitua "==" por "===" na condição e 0 por `null' no assinatura da função e seu problema vai estar resolvido. Confira: https://ideone.com/KE4nz0. Depois, poste você mesmo uma resposta aqui, explicando como PHP faz comparação de string com números :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
 private function mountTree($folders, $folder_id = '', $include_files = false)
    {
        $tree = [];
        foreach ($folders as $folder) {
            if (strcmp($folder['parent_folder'], $folder_id) == 0) {
                $children = $this->mountTree($folders, $folder['id'], $include_files);
                if ($children) {
                    $folder['children'] = $children;
                }
                if ($include_files) {
                    $folder['files'] = $this->getFilesByFolder($folder['id']);
                }
                $tree[$folder['name']] = $folder;
            }
        }
        return $tree;
    }
```

Após identificar que o problema era com o tipo de dados (inteiro e string) eu alterei o default do parâmetro `$folder_id` para `''` e também comparei as string com a função `strcmp`. Com isso a arvore é montada sem erros, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]